# How to install Heroku CLI on WSL 2?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, windows-subsystem-for-linux, heroku-cli

I have already an account on Heroku and a Heroku CLI running on my Windows terminal. As I have also installed a Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL2), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I'm trying to install Heroku CLI also on WSL2, to be accessed for this Shell.

However, it is not possible following closely the [Get Started heroku with ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby) nor for Windows neither for Ubuntu.

The first barrier is where the OpenSSL key need to be saved. According to the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby), it is said to extract the Izma with 7Zip,

> ...and then extract the tar file to :\openssl.

Doing so, the Heroku CLI can not find the OpenKey through Ubuntu Shell, producing many log advises when I run:

`sudo snap install heroku --classic`

from the [**tutorial**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#set-up).

The question is:

1) Is there a way for Heroku CLI, on my Ubuntu Shell, accessing that first key I previously installed on the `dir c:/openssl` on my Windows? or

2) I need to extract the key to the Ubuntu root?

Answer (score 35):

You can install *heroku-cli* with this simple install script by heroku:

`curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh`

Source: https://dev.to/wrightdotclick/heroku-cli-on-wsl-26fp

Comment: BTW, this command is also given at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install - but they come _after_ the `snap` suggestion, and the herkou docs don't say this is the right way to do it for WSL unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Heroku and it still doesn't work then just restart your terminal. It worked for me.

Comment: Yea, it works, typical linux issue)

Answer (score 0):

1) The answer for your first question is "no";

2) Yes, you need to extract the key to your Ubuntu root.

But not exactly a folder named "root" on your Ubuntu on Windows. You have to extract the key to the place your Ubuntu usually saves all keys:

`<your-user>/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/usr/include/openssl`

Use your Windows explorer to find the appropriated path for your case, the reason is: some folders names may change after you installing many others WLS.

After extracting the key, follow the steps from the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#set-up) as you would do if you were installing using  just Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Windows user, and you are using the Ubuntu terminal. first  make sure to delete everything that you installed before about heroku, And then try to run this command " `npm install -g heroku` " on the ubuntu terminal.

-g means "Global". I had a similar problem, this works for me.

Here you have more information about [Heroku information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#npm)

Comment: They say on the Heroku website that this is the installation method you should try to avoid.